# Amazon S3 download file exception: StreamSizeMismatchException

Tags: amazon-web-services, exception, amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file from an Amazon S3 bucket using the AWS SDK for .NET. However, I am encountering the following exception:

```
Amazon.S3.Model.StreamSizeMismatchException: 'The total bytes read 48881378 from response stream is not equal to the Content-Length 48883321 for the object test.zip in bucket testbucket.
```

an someone please help me understand what is causing this exception and how can I fix it?

Here are some additional details that might be helpful:

1. I am using the GetObjectAsync method to download the file.
2. The file is a zip archive that is approximately 46MB in size
3. I have verified that the bucket and object names are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't necessarily mean there is problem with the code, it is one of the exceptions that tells you the download failed. It could mean that the download was interrupted, and you could catch the exception and retry.

But if you are using the .NET SDK, you may have better results using the [TransferUtility](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingTheMPDotNetAPI.html), which is a higher level API and easier to work with. There are [some examples in .NET also](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_Scenario_UsingLargeFiles_section.html).

Comment: i try with high level api but problem is same

Comment: Does it happen with every file, or just one file in particular? If other (or smaller) files are able to download successfully it might mean it is a problem with that file.

Comment: I am able to Download Small File Not issue there .  Only issue have Large File more than 30MB . when i try with java i am able to download large file

Comment: Could you post the code you are using?